# Error: Captcha is needed

Tags: c#, вконтакте, vkontakte-api

Использую `wall.post` для постинга информации на стены вк. Если постить на несколько разных id, выдает ошибку "Ошибка с Captcha". Описание там такое: "Если какое-либо действие (например, отправка сообщения) выполняется пользователем слишком часто, то запрос к API может возвращать ошибку "Captcha needed"".

Чтобы обойти это ограничение, хочу после каждого постинга поставить `Thread.Sleep()`.

Вопрос: никто не знает, какое количество секунд оптимально ждать, чтобы обойти ограничение (чтоб ошибка не вылазила, но и пользователь постера слишком долго не ждал бы).
Какое время они там используют?

Comment: Не только из-за скорости запросов с одного IP может появляться капча: 

 * токен выдавался в одном гео регионе, а запросы идут с сервера в другом;
 * в нескольких постах подряд содержатся ссылки;
 * ещё какие-то подозрительный с т.з. ВК признаки возможного автопостинга, с которым они постоянно борются.

Answer (score 1):

А почему бы вам просто не взять уже готовый разбор каптчи и просто обрабатывать ее?

> 1. Выждать некоторое время (всегда
>    по-разному, в зависимости от
>    количества скачанного).
> 2. Залогиниться под другой учётной
>    записью (помогает только в том случае,
>    когда временные промежутки между
>    попытками поиска сильно
>    увеличиваются).

[Ссылка на это](http://vkmusic.citynov.ru/forum/oshibka-captcha-needed-t1869.html).
А мой тебе совет - просто экспериментируй!